# How to replace two entire columns in a df by adding 5 to the previous value?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, replace

I'm new to Python and stackoverflow, so please forgive the bad edit on this question.

I have a df with 11 columns and 3 108 730 rows.
Columns 1 and 2 represent the X and Y (mathematical) coordinates, respectively and the other columns represent different frequencies in Hz.

The df looks like this:

[df before adjustment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCacr.jpg)

I want to plot this df in ArcGIS but for that I need to replace the (mathematical) coordinates that currently exist by the real life geograhical coordinates.
The trick is that I was only given the first geographical coordinate which is x=1055000 and y=6315000.

The other rows in columns 1 and 2 should be replaced by adding 5 to the previous row value so for example, for the x coordinates it should be 1055000, 1055005, 1055010, 1055015, .... and so on.

I have written two for loops that replace the values accordingly but my problem is that it takes much too long to run because of the size of the df and I haven't yet got a result after some hours because I used the row number as the range like this:

```
for i in range(0,3108729):
    if i == 0:
        df.at[i,'IDX'] = 1055000
    else:
        df.at[i,'IDX'] = df.at[i-1,'IDX'] + 5
df.head()
```

and like this for the y coordinates:

```
for j in range(0,3108729):
    if j == 0:
        df.at[j,'IDY'] = 6315000
    else:
        df.at[j,'IDY'] = df.at[j-1,'IDY'] + 5
df.head()
```

I have run the loops as a test with range(0,5) and it works but I'm sure there is a way to replace the coordinates in a more time-efficient manner without having to define a range? I appreciate any help !!

Answer (score 1):

You can just build a range series in one go, no need to iterate:

```
df.loc[:, 'IDX'] = 1055000 + pd.Series(range(len(df))) * 5
df.loc[:, 'IDY'] = 6315000 + pd.Series(range(len(df))) * 5
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I tried your solution and it worked but not exactly the way I need it to. The code you wrote did adjust the first few lines accordingly but when I use ```df.tail()``` to check the end of the df, all row entries for the IDX and IDY columns have NaN entries. I'm completely lost as to why the adjustment bugged at some point. Any ideas?